# App shows in Application List but widget doesn't appear in Widget List (on Android 2.2 phone)

Tags: android-widget

I have created an Android widget application which installs fine on my HTC Sensation with Android 4.  I have also tested it using the AVD emulator and it works fine on Android 2.2, Android 2.33 and Android 4 emulators.

When a colleague installs it on his Android 2.2 phone the app installs and comes up with the welcome page, however the associated widget never appears in the Widget List so he can't add it to his home screen.  He says the app is installed on the phone and not an SD card and he has opened the application which is normally required to make the widget appear in the list.

Does anyone know how this can happen or what I can do to make the installation more robust?

Comment: did he try restarting the phone?

Comment: Thanks, yes a phone restart did to the trick.  He said he initially installed it on the SD card and then moved it to the phone.  Maybe that had an impact and then the restart sorted it out.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to have been caused by installing the application on the SD card first.  It was then moved it to the phone to try and get the widget to work but widget does not show in the Widget List. A phone restart sorted it out.